# Alignment of cell with defined width in scene2d.ui.Table does not work

Tags: libgdx

I have a problem with the alignment of the content of a cell if I give the cell a defined width.

Example:

```
table = new Table(skin);
table.add("Name1").uniform();
table.add("0").width(50).right();
table.add(":");
table.add("1").width(50);
table.add("Name2").uniform();
table.row();
```

Produce:

> |Name1|0_ _ *|:|1* _ _|Name2|

but I want this result:

> |Name1|_ _ *0|:|1* _ _|Name2|

If I modify the table like this it will work:

```
table = table =new Table(skin);
table.add("Name1").right();
table.add("0").right();
table.add(":");
table.add("1").left();
table.add("Name2").left();
table.row();

table.add("").uniform();
table.add("").width(50);
table.add("");
table.add("").width(50);
table.add("").uniform();
```

I do not understand why the first example does not create the same result?

Comment: Im having the same issue - did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Sorry but I was not able to solve it until now :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and turned debug on for all my tables, then I realized that when you use .add().width(x), it sizes the widget's width (shown as green lines), not just the cell's width (shown as red lines) as I expected and this makes the issue.

In your second example, you size your second row's empty cells and in first row, your label widgets are not sized 50 width, and can be aligned center or right.

This is a handicap what differs from HTML tables and it should be fixed. For now, your second example can be used as a solution and another one is (that what I use) using inner tables as widgets.

```
table.add(innerTable);
```

EDIT: And I've just found the third and the best solution for me while tampering. Just give alignment to the widget before adding it to table.

```
label.setAlignment(Align.right);
table.add(label).width(50);
```